# jquery array returning one undefined?

Tags: jquery, arrays, undefined, each

I am trying to get an array out of this html code to add boxes, having the numbers in their id, to my content:

```
<a href="#" data-box="38,39,40">An Array</a>
```

The boxes to add:

```
<div id="box38">
    ...
</div>
<div id="box39">
    ...
</div>
<div id="box40">
    ...
</div>
```

As there are also html lines like this:

```
<a href="#" data-box="24">No Array</a>
```

I also need something that detects if there are multiple values or just one. In this case I just used `if (theid.length > 2)` because the single values won't get longer then two characters.

The array should be `[38,39,49]` and it is, as `console.log(theid);` returns exactly this array.

```
var theid = $(this).data('box');
var newHTML = '';

if (theid.length > 2) {
    theid = theid.split(',');
    $.each(theid, function(idx) {
        newHTML += $('#box' + theid[idx]).html();
    });
} else {
    var newHTML = '';
    newHTML = $('#box' + theid).html();
    console.log(theid);
};
```

But if I then add `newHTML` to my existing content `content.html(newHTML);` there is always an "undefined" in front of the loaded boxes? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where are you declaring `newHTML` before using it inside the `each` loop?

Comment: You're concatenating a new string to a previously undefined one. `newHTML += ""` means `undefined += ""` in your current code.

Comment: edited the newHTML declaration, sorry I missed it. Okay Melancia thats an interresting point... so I should try to define the newHTML wirth just `=` instead of `+=` the first time?

Comment: The way your code looks now it's quite right, you can just remove the second declaration in your `else` condition.

Comment: Check @TravisJ answer below.

Comment: There is no need to distingush between the cases with one and multiple values. `split()` works perfectly fine in cases where the element you split by is not there and gives you an array with one item. Examples: `"38,39,40".split(",")` returns `["38", "39", "40"]` and `"24".split(",")` returns `["24"]`.

Comment: Also it's a bit silly to generate the divs, convert them to html (with `.html()` and then put the html into the target. For eaxmple, instead of `newHtml = $("#box" + id).html; content.html(newHtml);` you can append them directly: `content.append($("#box" + id));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a byproduct of variable hoisting. Since you are using the `+=` operator the string is being appended to the end of the variable `newHTML` which previously held undefined. You can look at it like this:

```
//hoisted
var newHTML = undefined;

var theid = $(this).data('box');

if (theid.length > 2) {
 theid = theid.split(',');
 $.each(theid, function(idx) {
    newHTML += $('#box' + theid[idx]).html();
 });
} else {
 /*var */newHTML = '';
 newHTML = $('#box' + theid).html();
 console.log(theid);
};
```